# Non-printable characters being returned from oracle when using Oracle Managed DataAccess in .NET 4.5.1

Tags: .net-4.5, oracle-manageddataaccess

We just migrated our VB.NET Web Application from .NET Framework 2.0 to 4.5.1 and as part of this migration we also updated the OLE DB driver to Oracle Managed Data Access Driver.

Turns out a few of the queries in the existing code were fetching low values (Non Printable characters, specifically chr(0).) empty string, 
but the new migrated code happens to returns Non Printable character as is (returned as "�"). Does any one know if this is due to migration of the Framework or the Oracle Managed Data Access Driver. 
Is there a global setting/configuration that can be done to not return these "Non Printable characters". to avoid go through the code and masking the string at multiple places ?